# Element 'css': This element is not expected. in Magento 2.2.5 (upgraded from Magento 2.1.9)

Tags: magento2.2, css, magento-2.2.5, exception

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css': This element is not expected.
>   Line: 542 facing this issue in 2.2.5.

I have upgraded from Magento 2.1.9 to Magento 2.2.5 version.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 3):

The node 'css' should be wrapped inside '**head**' as below.

```
<head>
    <css src="Lof_All::css/fix_magento2.css" />
</head>
```

**Check File:**

(assuming the theme is within `app/design/frontend/`)

`grep -r -i --include \*.xml '<css/meta/link..' app/design/frontend/`

**Check DB/Admin:**

Check admin  Layout XML Update: any <css/meta/link...>content outside ..

Comment: Fixed the issue and issue on the LOF module. thanks for ur input.

Comment: This is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing because there is layout file which has a  node. you should check your custom theme's **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** file if you have any css node, ( also check your **default_heads_block.xml** file if you have added any custom css file ) if you don't fine any then check layout of specific page where this error is showing.

if you are using linux / ssh ( run this command it would find and list the file where this is added / declared )

`grep -r -i --include \*.xml '<css' app/design/frontend/`

Comment: Hi Naveed , i have found 4 css nodes then what should i do next step ? Can u pls help me out.

Comment: update your question with that resulted code / record.

Comment: Fixed the issue and issue on the LOF module. thanks for ur input.