# Element 'css': This element is not expected in magento2.2.5

Tags: magento2, css, magento-2.2.5, exception

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css': This element is not expected. Line: 542 facing this issue in 2.2.5.

My store is working fine but suddenly it's throw error like **Element 'css':** This element is not expected

Does anyone have an idea?

I search this issue and found below link but not give solutions.
[Magento 2 Element 'file': This element is not expected](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231269/magento-2-element-file-this-element-is-not-expected)
[Element 'css': This element is not expected. in Magento 2.2.5 (upgraded from Magento 2.1.9)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246374/element-css-this-element-is-not-expected-in-magento-2-2-5-upgraded-from-mag)

Comment: Which solution did you try for resolving problem?

Comment: both solutions I tried.